# Stuck in Gmail API authentication process in Developer Console. Service Unavailable

Tags: gmail-api, developer-console

Pretty strait forward. I have my gmail account, and want to enable the Gmail API in the Google developer console / APIs/Library.

However every time I try to the enabling process will spin for a bit and then tell me the service is unavailable.

I've tried different browsers, different computers, different locations, etc. No dice.

I made a recording:
https://www.screencast.com/t/pyp5QwBqYVvX

Has anyone else run into something like this? Are their work arounds? I've submitted feedback to google but havent heard back yet.

Comment: I'm unable to see the cast, could you perhaps show a screenshot? Also, are the other members of the Resources tab working? `Cloud Platform Project` and `Google Advanced Services`?

Comment: Actually it turns out I just happened to be trying to activate the API service the same time the cloud migration was going on. I retried it the next day and it all worked, so we're good.

Comment: Good to know, glad the issue was solved!