# I cannot enable any google api

Tags: google-api, google-developers-console

In the google developer console:
I've been using google api's but now for some reason every single api's enable button is greyed out and next to it is the message "Page loading error. Refresh this page to try again."

Refreshing the page does nothing. It's been like this for over two days now.

Comment: Please post pictures of the apis you are having issues with or at least give us an idea of which apis you are having issues with.

Answer (score 1):

Try again now, I had the same problem and it fixed itself at midnight AST.

I think these questions from today are the same issue:

- [Why Can't I Click "Enable" in Google Cloud to Enable Map GeoCoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212051/why-cant-i-click-enable-in-google-cloud-to-enable-map-geocoding)
- [Stuck in Gmail API authentication process in Developer Console. Service Unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57210073/stuck-in-gmail-api-authentication-process-in-developer-console-service-unavaila)